# socket.on body executes more than one time

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

socket.on executes more than one time that causes if a user sends one message it will execute more three times that causes to dispatch more three times

```
useEffect(() => {
       setSocket(io("http://localhost:5000/chat", { query: { token: localStorage.getItem("jwtToken") } }));
    
       socket.on("send", function(data){
          
          dispatch(sendMessage(data));
       })
    }, [socket, setSocket, dispatch])
```

how to fix this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
useEffect(() => setSocket(io("http://localhost:5000/chat", { query: { token: localStorage.getItem("jwtToken") } })), [localStorage.getItem("jwtToken")]);

useEffect(() => {
    const listener = function(data){
        dispatch(sendMessage(data));
    };

    socket.addEventListener("send", listener);
    return () => socket.removeEventListener("send", listener);
 }, [socket])
```